# How to use Automapper with Unity

Tags: automapper, unity-container

I have been reviewing the official documentation, and use Automapper with Ninject, SimpleInjector, etc. which seems good to me.
I would like some example of how to register the profile with Unity container. (MVC5 and WebApi)

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile() 
    {
        CreateMap<someDto, someEntity>();
    }
}
```